# Print each item of foreach array on its own line

Tags: foreach, pgffor

I'm somewhat new to package `pgffor`. Is it only for drawing, or can it be used to iterate through a list of text? I'm trying to use it to output a simple list of items, vertically, but I'm having trouble forcing a line break between each item.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\degrees}[1]{\def\degs{#1}}

\degrees{{{B.S. University, 2000}, {M.S. University, 2002}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\ifdef{\degs}{%
    \foreach \x in \degs{%
        \x \par%
    }
}{}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I've tried `\\`, `\par`, `\newline`, `\linebreak` after outputting the item, but nothing works. Clearly I'm not understanding the innards of a `\foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `\foreach` only finds one item because you have too many braces around the array contained in `\degs`. Removing on level yields

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\degrees}[1]{\def\degs{#1}}

\degrees{{B.S. University, 2000}, {M.S. University, 2002}}

\begin{document}



\begin{center}
\ifdef{\degs}{%
    \foreach \x in \degs{%
        \x \par%
    }
}{}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So to answer your question: it is not only for drawing but can be used otherwise.

How can one debug this? For instance, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\degrees}[1]{\def\degs{#1}}

\degrees{{B.S. University, 2000}, {M.S. University, 2002}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{One brace less}

\begin{center}
\ifdef{\degs}{%
    \foreach \x in \degs{%
        \textbackslash x=\x \par%
    }
}{}
\end{center}


\subsubsection*{Original}

\degrees{{{B.S. University, 2000}, {M.S. University, 2002}}}

\begin{center}
\ifdef{\degs}{%
    \foreach \x in \degs{%
        \textbackslash x=\x \par%
    }
}{}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, how embarrassing! I thought you needed to pass the argument with braces around it to make it a list in the first place... I didn't realize the command syntax would read comma delimited arguments as a list already. Thank you!

Comment: @delrocco These extra braces *are* needed for arrays in pgf.